# Getting error adding worksheet and date

Tags: vba, excel

I am adding sheet in a workbook with name "xxx" and today date eg. xxx 6.2 
using vba but it does not allow. I am getting error 400

Here is my code

```
  Dim SheetName As String
  Dim dt As Date
  dt = Data
  SheetName = "xxx "
  'Dim WS As Worksheet
  Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = SheetName & dt
```

Comment: What is the error description? Did you click Help on it or trying Googling?  Also your question cannot be left like that.  The reason it won't let you format it as code is because there is a minimum 1:3 text:code ratio in questions.

Comment: I am getting below error.
Run-time error'1004':
Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: You said error 400, now it's 1004?

Comment: This question should be closed - simple compile would show your syntax error `Data` should be `Date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below as:

```
Sheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = SheetName & dt
```

is syntactically incorrect hence your error.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim SheetName As String
    Dim dt As Date
    'dt = "2018-06-02" '<== asssign date value to variable
    dt = Now    '<== Today's date
    SheetName = "xxx "
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = Sheets.Add '<== use Set for new worksheet object
    WS.Name = SheetName & Format$(dt, "yyyy-mm-dd") '<==cannot have "/" in name so use format to ensure outputs in legal way

End Sub
```